# How to make custom end user text in a form available for editing for a e.g. editor role?

Tags: 7, forms, nodes

Within a form build in a custom module trough the form api I'm using pieces of text (eula, help, hints) of which some of them need to be editable by my client (editor role).

For example:

```
$form['eula'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => t('This text need to be editable. I agree to be bound by bla bla bla.'),
  '#options' => array('Ja'=>'Ja / Yes'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
);
```

I want to facilitate a central point where those text strings (like #title) can be edited and a way I can retrieve them in this custom module.

What's best practice for this scenario to do so? 
Create a content type for this or perhaps use variable_set/get?

Basically I want one location where my client can edit all those text strings.
To use a content type for this and node_load() everytime feels a bit too much.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the string or text is passed via [t() function](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/t) you can override it using [String Overrides](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module. Here is a quote from module's project page:

> Provides a quick and easy way to replace any text on the site.

**UPDATE**

You can also use [Variable](https://www.drupal.org/project/variable) module. Quote from project page:

> ... provides a registry for meta-data about Drupal variables and some extended Variable API and administration interface.
>
> This is an API module so it must be installed only when other modules require it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm aware of that module and it's great. But since I'm also overriding some other strings there myself it get's cluttered pretty fast. I really want a single page (location) where only the strings are shown the client needs to edit.

Comment: Then in that case you will have to go the custom way and use the variable module http://drupal.org/project/variable.check it out.

Comment: That looks like what I need. Thanks...appreciated. The correct url http://drupal.org/project/variable